# Any possible way to change a .py but still run it?

Tags: python

I'm extremely new to coding and have almost no idea what I'm doing. I am trying to send a (.py) to someone but they do not have any version of python downloaded. I am wondering if there is any way to send it as a different file but still have them run it as they click on it? Would really appreciate some feedback.

Comment: If someone wants to execute a Python script, they need a Python runtime environment/interpreter. There are third-party tools such as PyInstaller that turn a Python script into a portable executable, but I have a feeling that's much too complicated.

Answer (score 3):

As you mention, if there is no python interpreter installed, you cannot run the .py file directly.

You can convert your .py to binary executable so it can be executed directly. You can use [PyInstaller](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/) for this.